# How to calculate what this power series converges against? (double factorials)

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, power-series, factorial

I'm working on my physics master course homework and I'm given the following equation out of nowhere:

$\displaystyle{
1 + \sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{z^n\left(\, 2n - 1\,\right)!! \over 2n!!}
={1 \over \,\sqrt{\,\vphantom{\large A}1 - z\,}\,}
}$

Now I don't need to prove it for my Homework, but still im wondering,
how one would calculate this series.
Of course it is not mentioned in the Homework, that this series doesn't converge for
all $z$ ( sloppy physicsy style, I know : ) ). Wolfram Alpha said, It only converges for 
$\,{\rm abs}\left(\, z\,\right) < 1$, which is a hint to the geometric series, but I have no idea how to account for the double factiorals.

Any hints?

Comment: you should also put the upper limit on the summation , I presume it is $\infty$.

Comment: Double Factorial means you just skip every second factor. For example 5!!=5*3*1 or 6!!=6*4*2. (The guy commenting on double factorials being too large withdrew his comment, I'm still leaving this here to avoid future questions)

Comment: $\displaystyle{{1 \over \,\sqrt{\, 1 - z\,}\,}
=\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{\left(\,2n - 1\,\right)!! \over \left(\, 2n\,\right)!!}\,z^{n}\,,\quad\left\vert\, z\,\right\vert < 1}$.

[See WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5Bz%5En+Factorial2%5B2+n+-+1%5D%2F%28Factorial2%5B2+n%5D%29%2C+%7Bn%2C+0%2C+Infinity%7D%5D).

Comment: This is a [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Derivation of the Series**

The Binomial Theorem says that
$$
\begin{align}
(1-x)^{-1/2}
&=1+\frac{(-\frac12)}{1}(-x)^1+\frac{(-\frac12)(-\frac32)}{1\cdot2}(-x)^2+\frac{(-\frac12)(-\frac32)(-\frac52)}{1\cdot2\cdot3}(-x)^3+\dots\\
&=1+\frac12x+\frac{1\cdot3}{2\cdot4}x^2+\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5}{2\cdot4\cdot6}x^3+\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot8}x^4+\dots\\
&=1+\frac{1!!}{2!!}x+\frac{3!!}{4!!}x^2+\frac{5!!}{6!!}x^3+\frac{7!!}{8!!}x^4+\dots
\end{align}
$$
$n!!=n(n-2)(n-4)\dots(1\text{ or }2)$

---

**Radius of Convergence**

Note that
$$
1\le\frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n)!!}=(2n+1)\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\le(2n+1)
$$
therefore
$$
\frac1{2n+1}\le\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\le1
$$
Using the formula for the [Radius of Convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Theoretical_radius), we get
$$
\frac1{\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}1^{1/n}}\le r\le\frac1{\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac1{2n+1}\right)^{1/n}}
$$
which gives a radius of convergence of $1$.

Comment: Wow thanks, a really easy solution :D

Comment: This is a nice solution, but it doesn't tell us whether this series converges at $x=1$, which I was hoping to learn. Mathematica suggests it does, but the root test and ratio test seem to be of no use.

Comment: @ziggurism: well, since $\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\ge\frac1{2n+1}$, and the harmonic series diverges, this series diverges at $x=1$ by the [Comparison Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test). However, the [Alternating Series Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) shows that the series converges for $x=-1$.

Comment: @robjohn: you caught me. to be honest the series I considered was $(2n-3)!!/(2n)!!$ (the series for $\sqrt{1-z}$) not $(2n-1)!!/(2n)!!$ (series for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z}}$.) I had assumed that they have the same convergence (since they are reciprocals, though why I thought this should give them the same convergence escapes me at the moment). I see now that they don't. $(2n-3)!!/(2n)!!$ is convergent (this is the one I tested in Mathematica), while $(2n-1)!!/(2n)!!$ doesn't. I could ask you why $(2n-3)!!/(2n)!!$ converges, I suppose, but maybe it's off topic and I should start a new question.

Comment: [new question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1515101/find-sum-infty-2n-3-2n)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can attack this problem. I will not write the full analysis, but enough to give an idea.  Start with assuming we have
$$
  \frac1{\sqrt{1-z}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^k
$$
Then, computing the square, we find that
$$
  \frac1{\sqrt{1-z}} \cdot \frac1{\sqrt{1-z}} = \frac1{1-z}= \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^k \cdot  \sum_{l=0}^\infty a_l z^l
$$
But that must be equal the usual geometric series, so the problem can be seen as "computing the (convolutional) square root of a power series. We get that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{l=0}^k a_k a_{l-k} =1,
$$
which then can be solved recursively.