# Show $\sum^\infty (2n-3)!!/(2n)!!$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, factorial

I would like to compute the sum $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(2n-3)!!}{(2n)!!},$ where the double exclamation point refers to [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial).

Using double factorial identities we get the ratio of the $(n+1)$<sup>th</sup> term to the $n$<sup>th</sup> as $\dfrac{2n-1}{2n+2}\to 1,$ so the ratio test is inconclusive. Also it is not alternating.

We can write the $n$<sup>th</sup> term as 
$$\dfrac{1}{2n}\cdot\dfrac{2n-3}{2n-2}\cdot\dfrac{2n-5}{2n-4}\cdot\dotsb\cdot\dfrac{3}{4}\cdot\dfrac{1}{2}$$
so we see that it looks like a harmonic series multiplied termwise by an increasing number of fractions between 1/2 and 1.

Wolfram alpha just reports that ratio test fails, but Mathematica claims it converges and its value is $0$, which is expected since this is the power series for $\sqrt{1-z}$ evaluated at $z=1$. How can we show convergence?

Comment: @imranfat: double factorial of negative arguments can be defined for odd arguments by the recursion relation $n!!=n\cdot (n-2)!!$ (which gives $(-1)!!=1$ and $(-3)!!=-1$). Or else just define them by convention. Anyway you like it, let's let the first two terms be -1 and 1/2.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thanks...

Comment: As an aside, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty \bigg[\frac{(2n-3)!!}{(2n)!!}\bigg]^2~=~\frac4\pi$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$a_n=\frac{(2n-3)!!}{(2n)!!} = \frac{1}{(2n-1)4^n}\binom{2n}{n} = O\left(\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}\right), $$
hence the series is convergent.

To find its value, we may recall that by the extended binomial theorem:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^n}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}, $$
hence it follows that:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{2n}}{4^n(2n-1)}\binom{2n}{n} = -\sqrt{1-x^2} $$
and our sum is just that series for $x=1$, hence zero.

That also follows by noticing that $a_n$ can be written in a telescopic fashion:
$$ \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}-\frac{(2n-3)!!}{(2n-2)!!} = \frac{(2n-1)!!-2n\cdot(2n-3)!!}{(2n)!!} = -a_n.$$

Comment: Can you say something about how you know $\dfrac{1}{(2n-1)4^n}\dbinom{2n}{n}$ has a growth rate of $\dfrac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}$? Is it [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)?

Comment: @ziggurism: yes it is.